Could I use numpy.arrays to represent the chromosome when solve Job scheduling in GA
I'm trying to solve a Job scheduling problem using a Rank-Based Encoding genetic algorithm that I envision encoding like this:
Represent the chromosome as an m x n matrix, each row of the array represents a job to be processed, and each value on it represents the priority value of this operation of job for this process. When decoding, I use a descending sort to order all the values in the chromosome, and then arrange these operation in that order by some rule.
I know that numpy's array manipulation can be faster with a smaller memory footprint than python's own list, so this time I'd like to try using numpy.narray to record the chromosome, but I'm not quite sure how to work around the fact that the actual length of each row in the matrix is not the same, since the number of operations passes needed for each job may be different.
Can I simply add a padding value such as -1 to the end of the array of those jobs that are shorter to make each row of the matrix the same length? Or will this result in poor computational performance?

Hard to answer as it's a bit unclear what kind of algorithmics / access-patterns will happen here (GA-experts maybe can guess better; i can't). Remarks: A: Measuring is better than guessing. Implement a small proof-of-concept (not a complete algo; only your hot-loop like elements) and measure it. B: If you can't vectorize your np.array ops, you probably won't see any speedup. Pythons slow interpreter and for-loops will dominate whatever array/list-mutation there is to happen. C: Needing to sort frequently (slow?) sounds like it will dominate asymptotically linear things like padding easily.

Or differently stated: Highly iterative code is probably not slow due to list vs. numpy (aka storage), but due to pythons interpreter / dispatching. The only thing making numpy-arrays faster is A: bypassing the interpreter by vectorization (hard to apply to many use-cases in discrete-optimization) OR being more B: cache-friendly. I would expect A to be more of an issue not being rectified by B easily.
